# Why doesn't TypeSynonymInstances allow partially applied type synonyms to be used in instance heads?

Tags: haskell

I know that [TypeSynomymInstances only allows fully applied type synonyms to be used in instance heads](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/TypeSynonymInstances), but it seems like it would be handy if I could use paritally applied type synonyms to be used as well.

For instance:

```
class Example e where
  thingy :: a -> b -> e a b

-- legit, but awkward
newtype FuncWrapper e a b = FuncWrapper { ap :: a -> e a b }
instance (Example e) => Example (FuncWrapper e) where
  thingy _ = FuncWrapper . flip thingy
funcWrapperUse :: (Example e) => e Int String
funcWrapperUse = thingy 1 "two" `ap` 3 `ap` 4 `ap` 5

-- not legal, but a little easier to use
type FuncSynonym e a b = a -> e a b
instance (Example e) => Example (FuncSynonym e) where
  thingy _ = flip thingy
funcSynonymUse :: (Example e) => e Int String
funcSynonymUse = thingy 1 "two" 3 4 5
```

Comment: Did you try `-XTypeSynonymInstances` in order to get your second version running (as suggested by GHC)?

Comment: @Landel: It doesn't like the fact that `FuncSynonym e` isn't fully applied.  Thus my question.

Comment: This is (related to) ticket [785](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/785), which is marked as `wontfix`.

Comment: `-XLiberalTypeSynonyms` lets you write and pass type synonyms

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Partially applied type synonyms are not allowed in Haskell at all.  A partially applied synonym is effectively a function whose inputs are the un-applied types and whose output is a type.  For example, here is an encoding of boolean logic:

```
type True x y = x
type False x y = y
type Not b x y = b y x
type And b1 b2 x y = b1 (b2 x y) y
type Or b1 b2 x y = b1 x (b2 x y)
```

To decide whether two partially applied type synonyms are equal, the type checker would have to decide whether functions are equal.  This is a hard problem, and in general it is undecidable.

Comment: Fair enough.  In my example all I use it for is a simple substitution, so it'd be nice if there were an option to just allow that, but then again, I don't work on GHC :).  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Another issue with allowing partially applied type synonyms is that they would make type inference and instance selection essentially impossible.  For example, suppose in the context of some program I wanted to use `thingy` at the type `Int -> String -> Int -> (Int, String)`.  `thingy` has type `forall a b e. a -> b -> e a b`, so we can unify `a` with `Int` and `b` with `String`, but if `e` is allowed to be a partially applied type synonym, we could have

```
e = FuncSynonym (,)
```

or

```
e = FuncSynonym' Int (,) where type FuncSynonym' x f a b = x -> f a b
```

or even

```
e = Const2 (Int -> (Int, String)) where Const2 a x y = a
```

The problem of type inference would become even worse than deciding equality of functions; it would require considering all functions with specified output on a particular input, or similar more complicated problems (imagine simply trying to unify `a b` with `Int`).

Answer (score 0):

As we known `Maybe`'s kind is `*->*`.

So it could be a instance of `Functor`

```hs
   instance Functor Maybe where
       fmap :: f -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
       fmap f Nothing = Nothing
       fmap f (Maybe x)  = Maybe (f x)
```

---

The first example:

```hs
   {-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}

   type MaybeAlias a = Maybe

   instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Functor (MaybeAlias Int) where
       fmap f functor = undefined
```

Under the effect of `TypeSynonymInstances` extension (almost like a String replace), it equals

```
      instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Functor Maybe where
       fmap f functor = undefined
```

It is ok, because `allow fully applied type synonyms to be used in instance heads`

---

See the other example:

```hs
   {-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}

   type MaybeAlias a b = Maybe
```

What's the kind of `MaybeAlias Int` now? It's kind is `*->*->*`.

Why?

As @heatsink comment above:

> A partially applied synonym is effectively a function whose inputs are the un-applied types and whose output is a type

Explain it now:

Under the defintion of `type MaybeAlias a b = Maybe` :

`MaybeAlias` like a partially applied function:

```hs
(MaybeAlias) :: a -> b -> Maybe
```

`MaybeAlias Int` like a partially applied function:

```hs
(MaybeAlias Int) :: b -> Maybe
```

The `Maybe` 's kind is `* -> *`,  `b` 's kind is `*`.

So `MaybeAlias Int` 's kind is `* -> (* -> *)` .

And `* -> (* -> *)` equals `* -> * -> *`.

**The root cause why the below code not working, because `Functor` typeclass only accept type that has kind `* -> *`,  not `* -> * ->*`!**

```hs
   {-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}

   type MaybeAlias a b = Maybe

   instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Functor (MaybeAlias Int) where
       fmap f functor = undefined
```

---

Why the below code not working?

```hs
class Example e where
  thingy :: a -> b -> e a b

-- legit, but awkward
newtype FuncWrapper e a b = FuncWrapper { ap :: a -> e a b }
instance (Example e) => Example (FuncWrapper e) where
  thingy _ = FuncWrapper . flip thingy
funcWrapperUse :: (Example e) => e Int String
funcWrapperUse = thingy 1 "two" `ap` 3 `ap` 4 `ap` 5

-- not legal, but a little easier to use
type FuncSynonym e a b = a -> e a b
instance (Example e) => Example (FuncSynonym e) where
  thingy _ = flip thingy
funcSynonymUse :: (Example e) => e Int String
funcSynonymUse = thingy 1 "two" 3 4 5
```

`Example` typeclass accept a type that has kind `* -> * -> *`

`FuncSynonym` like a partially applied function:

```hs
   FuncSynonym :: e -> a -> b -> (a -> e a b)
```

`FuncSynonym e` like a partially applied function:

```hs
   (FuncSynonym e):: a -> b -> ( a -> e a b)
```

`a` 's kind is `*`,

`b` 's kind is `*`,

`a -> e a b` 's kind `*`

`(FuncSynonym e)`'s kind is `* -> * -> *`

**`Example` typeclass accept a type that has kind `* -> * -> *`, but why still not work?**

**It's the other reason in [ghc issue 785](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/785) and [comment](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/8411#note_75813)**