# What's wrong with my Haskell type synonym?

Tags: haskell, ocaml, type-inference, hindley-milner, type-synonyms

I have two functions for controlling loops, [`continue`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Continuation_with_next_iteration) and [`break`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Early_exit_from_loops):

```hs
type Control a = (a -> a) -> a -> a

continue :: Control a
continue = id

break :: Control a
break = const id
```

Then, I wanted to simplify the `Control` type synonym. Hence, I wrote:

```hs
type Endo a = a -> a

type Control a = Endo (Endo a)

continue :: Control a
continue = id

break :: Control a
break = const id
```

However, when I tried to further simplify it I got an error:

```hs
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> type Endo a = a -> a
Prelude> type Duplicate w a = w (w a)
Prelude> type Control a = Duplicate Endo a

<interactive>:4:1:
    Type synonym ‘Endo’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
    In the type declaration for ‘Control’
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error. Perhaps you could enlighten me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As said by Fraser, this kind of stuff can't generally work because type partially applied type synonyms [make everything undecidable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4923883/745903).

However, if you chuck in the `-XLiberalTypeSynonyms` extension, GHC will inline the synonyms until it can work out the inference:

```hs
Prelude> type Endo a = a -> a
Prelude> type Duplicate w a = w (w a)
Prelude> type Control a = Duplicate Endo a

<‌interactive>:4:1:
    Type synonym ‘Endo’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
    In the type declaration for ‘Control’
Prelude> :set -XLiberalTypeSynonyms
Prelude> type Control a = Duplicate Endo a
```

Answer (score 9):

Type synonyms have to be fully applied al all times. You cannot partially apply them.

If you're intent on doing this, you will likely need to newtype it.

Comment: This. `Duplicate Endo a` is valid if `Endo` is a `data` or `newtype`, but *not* if it's just a `type`.

Comment: see [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/785) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922560/why-doesnt-typesynonyminstances-allow-partially-applied-type-synonyms-to-be-use) for more info. the gist is that inference on partially applied synonyms is undecidable