# Generalising class parameters

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families

Lets say I've got the class:

```
class C a b t where
  f :: (a, b) -> (t a, t b)
```

Now with this definition, I can define instances for say:

```
(a,b) -> (Maybe a, Maybe b)
(a,b) -> ([a], [b])
```

But not for (as far as I understand):

```
(a,b) -> (a,b)
(a,b) -> ((a, a), (b, b))
```

I could instead change my class definition like so:

```
type family T a b x

class C a b where
  f :: (a, b) -> (T a b a, T a b b)
```

Which would allow me to do the above, but then I'd only be able to declare one `f` for each `a` and `b`.

Basically I want to be able to pass a type family as `t` in the original definition, which is implicitly resolved by the type checker if known. I don't want to just make it `f :: (a, b) -> (c, d)` as I want to maintain the invariant that both `a` and `b` have the same thing done to them, so `swap . f` is the same type as `f . swap`. I'm thinking I might need [injective type families](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/InjectiveTypeFamilies) (from GHC 8.0) but I'm not sure. But maybe there's another way?

Comment: A non-answer: you might use `Identity` in the first case and a suitable newtype in the second one (I can't think of any standard one right now). That is a crude workaround, but it might prove less painful than the advanced trickery this seems to call for. By the way, the "I don't want to just make it `f :: (a, b) -> (c, d)` as I want to maintain the invariant..." sounds a lot like the issue of *lens* lenses being `Lens s t a b` [even though the four parameters are mutually dependent](http://comonad.com/reader/2012/mirrored-lenses) (see the "Why is it a Lens Family?" section of the post).

Comment: I think this is basically the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922560/why-doesnt-typesynonyminstances-allow-partially-applied-type-synonyms-to-be-use

Answer (score 5):

This may or may not answer your question depending on what you actually need to do.

A standard solution is to use a newtype to define new instances. E.g.

```
newtype Pair a = Pair (a, a)
instance C a b Pair where
   f = ...
```

However, this will cause `f` to have type

```
f :: (a, b) -> (Pair a, Pair b)
```

instead of the wanted

```
f :: (a, b) -> ((a, a), (b, b))
```

The latter can be recovered in a boring way:

```
f' :: (a, b) -> ((a, a), (b, b))
f' p = case f p of (Pair x, Pair y) -> (x, y)
```

Now, writing "adapter" functions such as `f'` feels redundant: after all we are simply removing a `newtype` wrapper, which does not change the runtime representation. Worse, this could be inefficient: consider transforming `[Pair a]` into `[(a, a)]`. To do that, we would need to map over the whole list, so we pay O(n) do do essentially *nothing*.

An efficient alternative can be constructed using [safe coercions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.8.1.0/Data-Coerce.html):

```
import Data.Coerce

f'' :: forall a b. (a, b) -> ((a, a), (b, b))
f'' = coerce (f :: (a, b) -> (Pair a, Pair b))
```

This allows the use of `newtype`s to drive instance selection, and yet remove them when they get in the way.

Now, if your aim really is to define new instances without `newtype`s, this does not help much. If instead you want a simple way to remove `newtype`s wrappers from instance methods, it can help.

Comment: `Data.Coerce` looks really interesting. Thanks for that answer.